# How can I print the 'route' list elements using jinja2 templates.?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am sending the response to the templates with name using form.How can I print the 'route' list elements using jinja2 templates. Below I am giving both my index.py page code and the desired output .Please suggest me the code which I should use in jinja template to obtain the expexted output.

```js
@app.route('/route',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
 form = Route()
 if request.method == 'POST':
  if form.validate_on_submit():
   tnum = request.form["T_No"]
   r = requests.get('https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/route/train/'+request.form['T_No']+'/apikey/<myapi>/').content
   return render_template('showRoute.html',form=r)
   return 'something wrong'
 return render_template('route.html',form=form)
```

```html
  
"route": [
        {
          "no": 1,
          "scharr": "SOURCE",
          "schdep": "06:15",
          "distance": 0,
          "halt": -1,
          "day": 1,
          "station": {
            "name": "KALKA",
            "code": "KLK",enter code here
            "lng": null,
            "lat": null
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the [json response](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) to `dict` and pass it to the template

```py
@app.route('/route', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Route()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            tnum = request.form["T_No"]
            r = requests.get('https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/route/train/'+request.form['T_No']+'/apikey/<myapi>/')
            try:
                data = r.json()
            except:
                data = None
            return render_template('showRoute.html', data=data)
    return render_template('route.html', form=form)
```

Then use the data in template

```html
{% if data %}
<table style="width:100%" border="3">
    <tr>
        {% for key in data["route"][0].keys() %}
        <th>{{ key }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for route in data["route"] %}
    <tr>
        {% for key,value in route.items() %}
        {% if key == 'station' %}
        <td>{{ value['name'] }}</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
<p>No Routes found!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Mr. waynetech thanks but  the above  code only show the train name and train number and remaining blank. where is the problem in jinja code.{% for train in data %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{ data[train].name }}</td>
   <td>{{ data[train].number }}</td>
  {% endfor %} 
  {% for route in data %}
   <td>{{ route['day'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ route['distance'] }}</td>
  {% endfor %} 
  </tr>

Comment: You want html or json response?  Add html you wrote in the above question

Comment: I got the response in json format but I want to print the 'station name' and 'station code' which are in the route list (the file I uploaded in the original  question above).please see the second file(file after python file) in my question .

Comment: I've updated the answer, assuming your routes are like {"routes": [{"no":1 ...}{}{}]}